# :hover is not working properly in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, iframe, hover

I have a simple CSS dropdown menu with an iframe inside it. When I hover my mouse over the dropdown menu, the menu drops down. But when my mouse hovers the iframe inside the menu, the menu goes back. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
<div id="comments">
  <a href="#" class="btn">View comments</a>
  <div id="comment-wrap">
    <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/comments.php?..."></iframe>
  </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
#comment-wrap{display:none;z-index:5;position:absolute;padding:10px;background-color:#fff;}
#comments:hover #comment-wrap{display:block;}
</style>
```

This works in the latest versions of FF, Chrome, and Opera.

P.S. The dropdown menu remain dropped down when my mouse is hovering the padding of #comment-wrap.

Comment: Which doctype do you use for that?

Answer (score 17):

I have faced similar problems while working with the :hover psuedo class. It started working fine when I changed the Document mode of the browser to IE 9 and the Browser mode also set to IE9. IE 9 has the document mode set to IE8 by default.

Additionally, you can add the following meta info in the head tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Vilas, can you explain /how/ to set the document/browser mode? I assume the document mode is a setting the page author sets somewhere in the markup, but the browser mode is a setting the user owns?

Comment: Yup I am referring to the Browser mode additionally you can add the following meta info in the head tag <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>

Comment: wow how did that meta tag work? it fixed my problem completely!

Comment: To manually change the way the browser views the page (for you browser specifically) open the `Developer Tools` by pressing `F12` and making sure that both your `Browser Mode` and `Document Mode` are properly set (`Browser Mode` should be your version of IE and `Document Mode` should be set to `Standards`)

Comment: @Johannes Should I ask all my users to do it? :P

Comment: Adding the meta tag solved the problem (and a few others!) for me

Answer (score 5):

I found to have the same problem and i know this is already an old post but i felt like i had to publish my solution. Basicly IE does not accept the `:hover` event for any tags other than `<a>` with specified `href` (wont work on early ie versions), unless you add `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` at the top. And that was it! Problem solved :).

Comment: Just love when i get a vote down with no explanation whatsoever :P. Easy to vote down, hard to justify? It would help me and whoever comes to SO and searches an answer for this question, to know why votes (up or down) are given. I shared my experience to help and add a diferent option. Often i found that the most voted answer is not the one that works for me. Not a personal issue, just trying to be constructive.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this seems to be a browser bug, going back many IE versions. You can use a JS solution as a backup to IE. I've created a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/L9SNy/), adapting code from [another solution](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aK21cwI1s-bQJ%3awww.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=154142%20iframe%20hover%20css%20ie&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=DCh&gl=us&strip=1) addressing this issue.

Hope that helps!

Edit: further testing in IE9 shows that though the iframe is displayed, hovering over the scrollbars hides it immediately. There is likely a more involved JS fix for this, but it's up to you if you'd like to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a hover issue in IE10 (not sure about lower versions) that was driving me crazy. I had my css hover set properly and it was for a div that contained an iframe. The issue was that when you hovered the div it would show the iframe but as soon as you tried to move the mouse into the iframe it would disappear again. I searched everywhere and found nothing for an acceptable answer for me except to use javascript or jquery. After days of trying to sort it out I found a very simple solution that worked for me. I simply removed the iframe from the div and used the object such as

```
<div class='showme'>links<div style='float:left;' class='showme_1'>
    <object type='text/html' data='http://www.google.com' style='width:100%; height:100%' border='0'>
    </object>
</div>
```

I hope this helps folks save a lot of research time.