# Hover effect doesn't work on IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Live site- http://www.orourkehospitality.com/hostedContent/williamsinn/

Hover effect doesn't work on IE9 but working perectly on Chrome, Safari, Mozila etc.
Check screenshot below.

Any idea what is the issue & how to fix? I will provide code if needed(that is too long for that reason i skip now).

[image]

Comment: Add this <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>.Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619156/hover-is-not-working-properly-in-ie9

Comment: tahts why nobody likes IE

Answer (score 0):

Add specific `width` and `height` for those images:

```
img.hover-images-flourish {
    width: 110px;
    height: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
<img class="hover-images-flourish" src="http://www.orourkehospitality.com/hostedContent/williamsinn/wp-content/themes/williamsinn/images/hover-flourish-top.png" style="margin-top: 63px;width:100px:height:100px">
```

I have added

```
width:100px:height:100px  in your style
```

or you could

change it in css too

```
  .hover-images-flourish {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }
```

**IMPORTANT**:

if the above fix  doesn't work

add

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if you **remove** these properties from **hover_pack.css**

there is a style applied for **IE only** which seems to cause the issue:

```
.ie a.b-animate-go img{
   width:100% !important;
   height:100% !important;
}
```